# GqlGen - Accessing query input params in field resolver

Tags: go, graphql, gqlgen

After generating the code using GqlGen there are some field resolvers method that has been created. I need to access the query input param in the field resolver but I'm not sure how to access it.
Do I need to get these values from context? Or is there any other way?

Query Resolver:

```
func (r *queryResolver) Main(ctx context.Context, device string) (*models.Main, error) {
...
}
```

Field Resolver:

```
// Version is the resolver for the version field.
func (r *mainResolver) Version(ctx context.Context, obj *models.Main) (*models.Version, error) {
        // I NEED TO ACCESS device param here which is passed in Main method
    panic(fmt.Errorf("not implemented: Version - version"))
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can find the arguments in the `FieldContext` of the parent resolver. You can get it with [`graphql.GetFieldContext`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/99designs/gqlgen@v0.17.20/graphql#GetFieldContext) like this:

```
// Version is the resolver for the version field.
func (r *mainResolver) Version(ctx context.Context, obj *models.Main) (*models.Version, error) {
    device := graphql.GetFieldContext(ctx).Parent.Args["device"].(string)
    // ...
}
```

The field `Args` is a `map[string]interface{}`, so you access the arguments by name and then type-assert them to what they're supposed to be.

If the resolver is nested several levels, you can write a function that walks up the context chain until it finds the ancestor that has the value. With Go 1.18+ generics, the function can be reused for any value type, using a pattern similar to json.Unmarshal:

```
func FindGqlArgument[T any](ctx context.Context, key string, dst *T) {
    if dst == nil {
        panic("nil destination value")
    }
    for fc := graphql.GetFieldContext(ctx); fc != nil; fc = fc.Parent {
        v, ok := fc.Args[key]
        if ok {
            *dst = v.(T)
        }
    }
    // optionally handle failure state here
}
```

And use it as:

```
func (r *deeplyNestedResolver) Version(ctx context.Context, obj *models.Main) (*models.Version, error) {
    var device string 
    FindGqlArgument(ctx, "device", &device)
}
```

If that doesn't work, try also with [`graphql.GetOperationContext`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/99designs/gqlgen@v0.17.20/graphql#GetOperationContext), which is basically undocumented... (credit to [@Shashank Sachan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5377229/shashank-sachan))

```
graphql.GetOperationContext(ctx).Variables["device"].(string)
```

Comment: It's giveng blank map for .Parent.Args

Comment: I was able to find it in operation context
```graphql.GetOperationContext(ctx).Variables["device"].(string)```

Comment: @ShashankSachan if you're still interested, I added a generic function to walk up the FieldContext ancestors